# How to fix VIM omnifunc to work with $this->variable->__AUTOCOMPLETE__

Tags: php, vim, omnicomplete

How do i get VIM omnifunc to work with this:

```
$this->temp = new Temp();
$this->temp-> // i don't get the correct completion choices....
```

BUT THIS WORKS:

```
$temp = new Temp();
$temp-> // i get the right list of completion choices here....
```